# Generate XYZ coordinates of DEM mesh/grid

Tags: gdal, dem, elevation, vector-grid, mesh

Is there a way to generate a wire grid of plain text XYZ coordinates starting and ending points for each wire segment? I want to generate them from a digital elevation model. Preferably with gdal/qgis and python. I have experience with gdal and python, I just don't know how to get started in this case.

I'd like to import the ground into an antenna modeling software.

Comment: What's a "wire grid"? A square grid? Where are you getting the Z (height?) coordinates from? Do you already have a digital elevation model? Can you give an example of the inputs and outputs that you want?

Comment: Yes a square grid. The coordinates would be from a dem

Comment: So your input is the (x,y) bounding box, the grid cell size, and the output is a CSV of (x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2) where each row defines a single side of a grid cell. Is that right? Do you care about the order of the sides in the CSV? Don't think there's anything off the shelf to do this, a short python script would be needed.

Comment: That's exactly right. I don't even know how to start extracting that info from a dem.

Comment: Do you have any python programming knowledge? Or other programming languages? Or GIS experience? Can you edit your question to clarify the problem using the info in my last comment?

Comment: I have edited the question.